# Spring @Async and Synchronized

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, concurrency, junit

I have a Spring-based asynchronous method (annotated with `@Async`) that I want to pause in the case that an error event happened a certain number of times.  Since there may be more than one thread doing the same kind of thing, I tried a static `AtomicInteger` (`MY_COUNT`) so that all threads can be aware of the count, and to make use of the built-in concurrency `AtomicInteger` provides.

In my unit tests (run with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` in Eclipse), all is well until the thread hits `MY_COUNT.incrementAndGet()`.  Then the thread just disappears.  No exception, nothing.  The async worker thread just disappears.  I tried taking out the `AtomicInteger` and just using `synchronized` methods, but the same thing happens.

Question: is there some kind of under-the-hood interaction between `@Async` and synchronization?  Is it not possible to combine the two?

---

EDIT: more info: it appears that it has something to do with synchronization scope (if that's the right term).  Once I removed the `static` designation from the counter variable, it still bombed; but then when I changed it to an `Integer` and moved the increment code to its own synchronized method, then the code proceeds.  I haven't debugged the underlying Spring code; are there any Spring experts which might be able to shed light on this behavior?

Comment: Mostly likely an exception is being swallowed - not reported on the console maybe due to your logging configuration. Can you put a try catch block around the problematic code

Comment: @AaronSheffey: Maybe you can provide a code snippet for critical parts? `static` modifier is appropriate for counter variable, otherwise each thread has it's own monitor. Also interesting to look at stackstrace at the point when execution is in method, annotated by `@Async`.

Answer (score 4):

No, async should not affect the behavior of the atomic integer.

With the given information, the only logical conclusion is that there is some exception that is not getting reported.

if it is possible for you, try setting the Uncaught exception handler

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html

In the handler, ensure that you get the trace printed at the very least.

If this does not give you the solution, or you have a problem setting up an uncaught exception handler, post your code, so that we can help you.